# How to make IP address show my wordpress not apache?

Tags: wordpress

I made a separate site for development, but I can only access to my wordpress site with 123.45.678.90/wordpress not 123.45.678.90. My IP is point to the default apache page (I want it to be mine wordpress page). In addition, for admin login when I type 123.45.678.90/wordpress/wp-admin it takes me back to the default apache page not the wordpress login. Thanks!!

In /etc/apache2/sites-enabled I have two conf. Not sure if it would help.

```
000-default.conf 
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet




wordpress.conf 
Alias /blog /usr/share/wordpress
<Directory /usr/share/wordpress>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride Limit Options FileInfo
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share/wordpress/wp-content>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Possible by creating a symlink to the wordpress folder containing the index.html file:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/622572/how-to-use-a-symlink-in-apache-web-server